# Does Apple provide a UI for editing/adding Reminders?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, eventkit

I know there is an API for adding a reminder programatically. But is there a view controller for reminders? I've looked in EventKitUI framework, but I'm not sure if `EKEventEditViewController` works for reminders, or only for calendar items.

Like Apple provide ones for SMS, Mail, Calendars, Twitter, Facebook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing like this for reminders. The only option as of iOS 6 is to make your own UI and follow the guide that Aadhira posted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could be able to edit Reminders also.

Check the [Calendar and Reminders Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingReminders/ReadingAndWritingReminders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765-CH5-SW1)

Also check the sample code [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Listings/Classes_RootViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010160-Classes_RootViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_4)

Comment: I cant see where in the example code there is anything about reminders. And the guide just says about a UI for calendars.